# Which is the real ASP.NET Boilerplate project?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

Might be a dumb question for many but we are thinking of adopting ASP.NET Boilerplate for our next project. Just a bit confused as there seems to be 2 different websites for it and 2 different Git repositories.

First one is 
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/
and second is 
https://abp.io/.

Both have their own Git repositories and Stack Overflow tag. I'm totally confused as to which one is the most correct project to use.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

ABP Framework (abp.io) is a rewrite and the next version of ASP.NET Boilerplate (aspnetboilerplate.com) based on lessons learned and with less backward compatibility to maintain.

Both are actively maintained.

## ASP.NET Boilerplate

- mature framework, since February 2014
- current version: v6.0, released November 2020
- has commercial base solution ASP.NET Zero (aspnetzero.com)

**Tech**

- monolith architecture, but supports modules
- supports ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET MVC 5
- supports EF Core and EF 6

## ABP Framework

- modern framework, since June 2018
- current version: 4.0.1, released December 2020
- also has an extended commercial edition (commercial.abp.io)

**Tech**

- microservices architecture
- supports ASP.NET Core only
- supports EF Core and MongoDB

Comment: Thanks @aaron .. that helps a lot. We do have a plan to eventually go for ASP.net Zero so we may go ahead with ASP.NET Boilerplate 

Have you got any experience with implementing either of them. Any suggestions to avoid pitfalls :) ?

Comment: I implemented a work project using ASP.NET Boilerplate (specifically [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template)), before becoming an active contributor to both ASP.NET Boilerplate and ASP.NET Zero from June 2017 to June 2019.

I would say avoid re-inventing/over-customising what ASP.NET Boilerplate provides. It works great out-of-the-box with minimal configuration. Do search the documentation, GitHub, Stack Overflow (and premium forum for ASP.NET Zero) before asking questions — you'll get to know and appreciate the framework.

Comment: By the way, the ABP framework supports the monolithic arch, however, it is ms-friendly thanks to its higher modularity "One common advice to start a new solution is always to start with a monolith, keep it modular, and split into microservices once the monolith becomes a problem. This makes your progress fast in the beginning especially if your team is small and you don't want to deal with challenges of the microservice architecture." https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.4/Microservice-Architecture#microservice-for-new-applications

Answer (score 0):

One aspect not mentioned by the answers are the licenses:

[ABP.IO is LGPL](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/LICENSE.md)

[AspNetBoilerplate is MIT](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/LICENSE.md)

This should be considered when you think about how do you market/sell the product you want to build on top.

Answer (score 0):

ABP Framework is the successor of the open source ASP.NET Boilerplate framework. This guide aims to help you to migrate your existing solutions (you developed with the ASP.NET Boilerplate framework) to the ABP Framework.

ASP.NET Boilerplate is being actively developed since 2013. It is loved, used and contributed by the community. It started as a side project of a developer, but now it is officially maintained and improved by the company Volosoft in addition to the great community support.

ABP Framework has the same goal of the ASP.NET Boilerplate framework: Don't Repeat Yourself! It provides infrastructure, tools and startup templates to make a developer's life easier while developing enterprise software solutions.

See the introduction blog post if you wonder why we needed to re-write the ASP.NET Boilerplate framework. https://blog.abp.io/abp/Abp-vNext-Announcement

Answer (score -9):

If we'd think it's Angular;

- `ASP.NET Boilerplate` = `AngularJS`
- `ABP.IO` = `Angular (the new)`