# The type '' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntityDto' in the generic type 'ICrudAppService'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, abp

I was going through a tutorial on abp.io:
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Tutorials/Part-1?UI=MVC#create-the-application-service

and I created the service:

```
using Abp.Application.Services;

public interface IBookAppService : 
    ICrudAppService< //Defines CRUD methods
        BookDTO , //Used to show books
        Guid, //Primary key of the book entity
        PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto, //Used for paging/sorting on getting a list of books
        CreateUpdateBookDto, //Used to create a new book
        CreateUpdateBookDto> //Used to update a book
{

}
```

but the interface is showing an error:

> The type '`BookDTO`' cannot be used as type parameter '`TEntityDto`' in the generic type or method '`ICrudAppService<TEntityDto, TPrimaryKey, TGetAllInput, TCreateInput, TUpdateInput>`'. There is no implicit reference conversion from '`BookDTO`' to '`Abp.Application.Services.Dto.IEntityDto<System.Guid>`'.

`BookDTO` is as follows:

```
using Volo.Abp.Application.Dtos;

public class BookDTO : AuditedEntityDto<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public BookType Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub.

Comment: https://github.com/udaysoni18/Abp-Project - repo Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing:

- `Abp.Application.Services.ICrudAppService<TEntityDto, TPrimaryKey, ...>`
- `Volo.Abp.Application.Dtos.IEntityDto<TKey>`

For ABP Framework (abp.io), use the `Volo.Abp` package:

- `Volo.Abp.Application.Services.ICrudAppService<TEntityDto, in TKey, ...>`

Related: [Which is the real ASP.NET Boilerplate project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58090626/8601760)

## Files to change

IBookAppService.cs:

```cs
// using Abp.Application.Services;
// using Abp.Application.Services.Dto;
using Volo.Abp.Application.Dtos;
using Volo.Abp.Application.Services;
```

BookAppService.cs:

```cs
// using Abp.Application.Services;
// using Abp.Application.Services.Dto;
// using Abp.Domain.Repositories;
using Volo.Abp.Application.Dtos;
using Volo.Abp.Application.Services;
using Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories;
```

CreateUpdateBookDTO.cs:

```cs
// using Abp.AutoMapper;
```

Acme.BookStore.Application.Contracts.csproj:

```html
<!-- <PackageReference Include="Abp" Version="5.6.0" /> -->
<!-- <PackageReference Include="Abp.AutoMapper" Version="5.6.0" /> -->
<PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp" Version="2.6.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.AutoMapper" Version="2.6.2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

CreateUpdateBookDto must be the same primary key type.

```cs
public class CreateUpdateBookDto: AuditedEntityDto<Guid> {
}
```

Comment: How did you infer this from the question?

Comment: I have worked in abp and that part is missing in their documentation. Hope that worked for you

Comment: No it didn't work. Kindly find repo project- https://github.com/udaysoni18/Abp-Project

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same issue and fixed it by changing the DTO inheritance
**from** `MyDto : AuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>`
**to** `MyDto: AuditedEntityDto<Guid>`