# ABP Missing LIBS directory

Tags: abp

The LIBS directory is missing when I create and download the ABP project.
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X8bi.png)

Comment: ABP Framework or ASP.NET Boilerplate? Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58090626/8601760

Answer (score 2):

Just Right Clicked On `libman.json` > `repair lib`/`Restore Client-Side` libraries. It is not updated in the documentation at the time of answering this question.

[Issue 5322](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/5322)