# How can I customize my _Layout [abp] framework, abp.io?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, abp

I am new to ABP Framework ([abp.io](https://abp.io)).

I want to customize _layout.cshtml.

It seems the _layout is in base classes.
So how can I override it.
And design my own _layout and use over all pages ?

Comment: ABP Framework is different from ASP.NET Boilerplate; the former is vNext of the latter. See: [Which is the real ASP.NET Boilerplate project?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58090974/8601760)

Comment: Lots of thanks @aaron,
I read your comment, where you referenced,
It was so helpful and time saving!
According to your comments, it seems I start my project with asp.net boilerplate, due to better documentation and knowledge base and my thin knowledge about ABP.
So is it possible to do my question, in asp.net boilerplate ?

Answer (score 1):

to do what you mention you must go to mvc / Views / Shared / Layout / _Layout.cshtml there you can customize the default layout.  In case you want to override the layout on a particular page you must set it to null, Layout = null

Comment: Thank you @Washyn Heloo.
As I mentioned, I asked my question in [abp] [asp.net boilerplate] framework.
This is deferent from asp.net MVC