# Policy-based Authorization not working with [Authorize] attribute in ABP Boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, abp, asp.net-authorization

I am working on an ASP.NET Core application using ABP (ASP.NET Boilerplate) as the framework. I want to implement policy-based authorization in my application using the standard `[Authorize]` attribute provided by ASP.NET Core.

To achieve this, I have defined custom authorization policies using `services.AddAuthorization()` in the `ConfigureServices` method of my `Startup.cs`. I have also registered the policies using `options.AddPolicy()`.

However, when I decorate an endpoint with the `[Authorize]` attribute and provide the name of the policy, the policy-based authorization is not working as expected. It seems that the `[Authorize]` attribute is not recognizing the registered policies, and the access to the endpoint is not being restricted based on the specified policy.

Is there any additional configuration or specific steps required to use policy-based authorization with the `[Authorize]` attribute in ABP Boilerplate? How can I make sure that the `[Authorize]` attribute works with my custom policies?

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Other services configuration...

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            policy.RequireClaim("Role", "Admin");
            
        });
    });
}
```

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]
public IActionResult SecureEndpoint()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: ASP.NET Boilerplate and ABP framework are different. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58090974/2594735 for details.